# How to filter out multiple specific keys and values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects. I want to filter out only few of them, particularly the ones containing numbers.

```
const arr = [
    {
      Title: "Joker",
      Year: "2019",
      Rated: "R",
      Released: "04 Oct 2019",
      Runtime: "122 min",
      Genre: "Crime, Drama, Thriller",
      Director: "Todd Phillips",
      Writer:
        "Todd Phillips, Scott Silver, Bob Kane (based on characters created by), Bill Finger (based on characters created by), Jerry Robinson (based on characters created by)",
      Actors: "Joaquin Phoenix, Robert De Niro, Zazie Beetz, Frances Conroy",
      Plot:
        "In Gotham City, mentally troubled comedian Arthur Fleck is disregarded and mistreated by society. He then embarks on a downward spiral of revolution and bloody crime. This path brings him face-to-face with his alter-ego: the Joker.",
      Language: "English",
      Country: "USA, Canada",
      Awards: "Won 2 Oscars. Another 57 wins & 163 nominations.",
      Poster:
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      Ratings: [
        { Source: "Internet Movie Database", Value: "8.6/10" },
        { Source: "Rotten Tomatoes", Value: "69%" },
        { Source: "Metacritic", Value: "59/100" }
      ],
      Metascore: "59",
      imdbRating: "8.6",
      imdbVotes: "665,555",
      imdbID: "tt7286456",
      Type: "movie",
      DVD: "17 Dec 2019",
      BoxOffice: "N/A",
      Production: "Warner Bros. Pictures",
      Website: "N/A",
      Response: "True"
    }
  ];
```

Initially Api response was in object, so I converted the object to an array somehow. Now I want to filter out the numbers to compare. Here's what I tried:

```
const makeArr = obj => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      arr.push({
        [key]: value
      });
    }
    return arr.filter(item => {
      if (Object.values(item).includes(isNaN(parseInt(Object.values(item))))) {
        return item;
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why converted API response object to array? You can iterate over an object using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
const obj =     {
      Title: "Joker",
      Year: "2019",
      Rated: "R",
      Released: "04 Oct 2019",
      Runtime: "122 min",
      Genre: "Crime, Drama, Thriller",
      Director: "Todd Phillips",
      Writer:
        "Todd Phillips, Scott Silver, Bob Kane (based on characters created by), Bill Finger (based on characters created by), Jerry Robinson (based on characters created by)",
      Actors: "Joaquin Phoenix, Robert De Niro, Zazie Beetz, Frances Conroy",
      Plot:
        "In Gotham City, mentally troubled comedian Arthur Fleck is disregarded and mistreated by society. He then embarks on a downward spiral of revolution and bloody crime. This path brings him face-to-face with his alter-ego: the Joker.",
      Language: "English",
      Country: "USA, Canada",
      Awards: "Won 2 Oscars. Another 57 wins & 163 nominations.",
      Poster:
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGVjNWI4ZGUtNzE0MS00YTJmLWE0ZDctN2ZiYTk2YmI3NTYyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      Ratings: [
        { Source: "Internet Movie Database", Value: "8.6/10" },
        { Source: "Rotten Tomatoes", Value: "69%" },
        { Source: "Metacritic", Value: "59/100" }
      ],
      Metascore: "59",
      imdbRating: "8.6",
      imdbVotes: "665,555",
      imdbID: "tt7286456",
      Type: "movie",
      DVD: "17 Dec 2019",
      BoxOffice: "N/A",
      Production: "Warner Bros. Pictures",
      Website: "N/A",
      Response: "True"
    }

for (let key in obj) {
   if (!isNaN(obj[key])) {
     console.log(key, obj[key]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parseInt does properly works on primitives, so iterate over the object values and check with !isNaN(parseInt(value))